# Error sending email using PHP mail() on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, email, sendmail

I used to be able to send email using the simple mail() in PHP although since I have upgraded to the latest PHP I am unable to send emails.

When I look at the email log I get the following:

```
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/pickup[26503]: 384B6246803: uid=70 from=<_www>
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/master[26709]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/cleanup[26680]: 384B6246803: message-id=<20110629201449.384B6246803@example.com>
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/qmgr[26504]: 384B6246803: from=<_www@example.com>, size=351, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/local[26683]: 384B6246803: to=<ben@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "ben")
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/cleanup[26680]: 3C318246805: message-id=<20110629201449.3C318246805@example.com>
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/qmgr[26504]: 3C318246805: from=<>, size=2033, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/bounce[26684]: 384B6246803: sender non-delivery notification: 3C318246805
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/qmgr[26504]: 384B6246803: removed
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/local[26683]: 3C318246805: to=<_www@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jun 29 21:14:49 Johns-MacBook postfix/qmgr[26504]: 3C318246805: removed
```

Comment: That's a mail bounce error. Unless PHP's filling in the wrong address, it can't do anything about bounces. Check your postfix setup.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? If so, and if my answer didn't solve the problem, would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: This just helped me. It's on topic. Should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fix the `fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable` problem:**

Have a look at your `php.ini` file and make sure that you can see this line:

```
sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i
```

or

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

It shouldn't have any quotes around it and that there is not semi-colon (;) before it. If it's not there or different, change it to match one of the line above.

If that doesn't help, have a look at http://switch.richard5.net/2006/08/19/fatal-open-lock-file-pidmasterpid/ and see if that helps. Since you've updated PHP, I doubt that postfix is the problem but you never know.

**Also:**

You may have postfix configuration issues. It's trying to deliver using the `local` relay. If the e-mail your trying to send to isn't one on the local server, you might want to check your `/etc/mailnames` and in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` check `myhostname`, `mydomain` and `myorigin`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but sadly changing the sendmail_path has no difference. Obviously restart apache after change. 

I have always had a problem on a windows pc, although normally it seems to just work on the linux/mac setup.

Comment: @John Magnolia - The problem you seem to be having can happen if your server is configured as `host.domain.tld` and you're sending to `user@domain.tld`. Have you checked your `main.cf`, `/etc/mailnames` and `/etc/hostname`? Postfix seems to think that the user you're trying to e-mail to is "local" (as it should deliver to itself instead of sending it through SMTP to another server).

Comment: My main.cf file contains the 'myhostname' with the correct domain. All others are commented out. I can't think what else to try. I have even tried reinstalling everything via Macports and still get the same errors. Can it be to do with disabling the Mac Web Sharing?

Comment: @John Magnolia - Is `myhostname` the domain you're trying to send to? And if it is, are you hosting the e-mail no the same server? If no, you need to change `myhostname` to something else. And some of the other settings "may" need to be changed to.

Comment: Is there a reason this now doesn't work. When before the standard mail() would work every time without configuring anything. I presumed this was a mac thing that handled the sending of mail.

Comment: So you mean I can't have the same domain as I use on my production server? I am not bothered how the emails are sent for my development local server, I just want it to work so I can test a html email template I am writing

Comment: @John Magnolia - If you configure the local server to think it's "example.org" even though it's not, when you send mail to "example.org", it'll try to send it as if it were a local user on the server. So, no you can't. You're "development" machine or the "staging" server shouldn't think they're the "production" one. Of course, the PHP can send mail to the same address but the servers need to be configured as different ones. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Set your relayhost

```
sudo postconf -e relayhost=<your-isp’s-smtp-server>
```